# Is one connection is enough in nodejs using mongoose driver for concurrent request in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to have one single connection poolsize { poolSize: 1 } for multiple and concurrent webservice hit in mongodb

Will it reuse the connection or will throw any exception

I'm Using mongoose driver in nodejs and mongoDB as database.

Comment: Why would you want to limit scalability that way? That would mean there would be only one active request in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will reuse the connection, but it will slow down your database calls, as there is a limit of only one active connection to the database. This will cause issues when you scale up to higher loads.